# SQL Inheritance, get by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance

This question aims to get the most clean and "best" way to handle this kind of problem.

I've read many questions about how to handle inheritance in SQL and like the `Table Per Type` model most and would like to use it. The problem with this is that you have to know what type you are going to query to do the proper join.

Let's say we have three tables:`Son`, `Daughter` and `Child`.

[image: Database Model]

This works very well if you for example want to query all daughters. You can simply join the child and get all the information.

What I'm trying to do is to query a `Child` by ID and get the associated sub class information. What I could do is to add a column `Type` to the child and select the associated data with a second select, but that does not seem pretty nice. Another way to do it would be to join all sub tables, but that doesn't seem to be that nice either.

Is there an inheritance model to solve this kind of problem in a clean, nice and performant way?

I'm using MySQL btw

Comment: Any common properties between the two types should go in the master table... the two type tables are specifically for storing properties that are specific to each type.  As such, it doesn't really make any sense to say "get me all of the information from either type regardless of what it is"... what use case would you have for that?

Comment: by the way, this is called a one to one relationship... inheritance is a thing of OOP, not database schemas.

Comment: @jdl134679 It's a ShareX Server (pastebin and imgur combined basically), the keys are the IDs in the URL, for example pastebin.com/nSdhrA (just a random url I made up). But as I want to handle images different than text or code, I need one master lookup table (in order to check if the ID even exists) and the sub tables holding specific data for the upload type.

Comment: I share your doubt about this model, but I also agree to @jdl134679's first comment: Assume that you have 1 child and 20 derivates, each with 5 different columns (which are specific to the derivates). What would you expect to see in your resulting query? 100 columns? What do to with them? So in short, yes, I agree, from a theoretical position this question is valid, but what is its practical purpose? In which context do you want to apply such a query? Compare it with an OOP: there you also make use of only one derivate at a time....

Comment: I've used 1:1 tables many a time (most often for master inventory/part number of different classes of products, in manufacturing) - there's nothing wrong with them, I'm just not clear on what you're looking to accomplish.  If you only want to deal with images, query only the images portion.  There's little practical use to trying to query distinct properties of, say image and text/code at the same time.

Comment: So how would you implement it then? Subtype in the "master" table and a second select on the corresponding sub table for the type specific data?

Comment: How would I implement what?  I don't know what you need to do.  Update your question with real tables, real data and a real expected result and we can help, but I can't quite see what it is you hope accomplish, so I can't offer much in terms of advice on how to get there...

Comment: The Server gets the http request domain.com/randomID. The server then selects this randomID and displays the result (-> 404 if the id was not found in the master table (in this case the Child table), formatted code it it was a text upload and the image if it was an image upload). Different upload types have different data associated (the original filename for files/images for example). Currently I'm storing all data in one single table and I just nulled the filename column, but that doesn't seem nice and clean. So basically I need a SQL model which basically acts like a Map<ID, Child> in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your detailed definition in the comment with the use case

> The Server gets the http request domain.com/randomID.

it becomes apparent, that you have a single ID at hand for which you want to retrieve the attributes of derived entities. For your case, I would recommend to use the LEFT JOIN approach:

```
SELECT age, 
  son.id is not null as isSon,
  randomColumn,
  daughter is not null as isDaughter,
  whatEver

FROM child
  LEFT JOIN son on child.id = son.id
  LETT JOIN daughter on child.id = daughter.id

WHERE
  child.id = @yourRandomId
```

This approach, BTW, stays very close to your current database design and thus you would not have to change much. Yet, you are able to benefit from the storage savings that the improved data model provides.

Besides that, I do not see many chances to do it differently:

- You have different columns with different datatypes (esp. if looking at your use case), so it is not possible to reduce the number of columns by combining some of them.
- Introducing a `type` attribute is already rejected in your question; sending single `SELECT` statements as well.

In the comment you are stating that you are looking for something like `Map<ID, Child>` in MySQL. Please note that this java'ish expression is a compile-time expression which gets instantiated during runtime with the corresponding type of the instance. SQL does not know the difference between runtime and compile-time. Thus, there is also no need for such a generic expression. Finally, also please note that in case of your Java program, you also need to analyse (by introspection or usage of `instanceof`) which type your `value` instance has -- and that is also a "single-record" activity which you need to perform.

Comment: The java example was only to further clarify what I'm basically trying to do. It's written in php anyway, but I thought it would be more clear this way.
I mentioned the "joining all sub tables" in my quesion, too. Would this be the cleanest way? How would I be able to differentiate the type after the select?

Comment: Oh, scratch the type one, the additional column specifies the type, didn't see this

Comment: Conerning "joining all sub tables": I personally would say, yes - here's why: By this you only trigger one roundtrip to the DB, thus the parse only needs to run once. Multiple single requests would cost much more, and your coding on the PHP side would be much more complicated (and running them in parallel - which is what you could do - would be a mess). NULL values don't count much when transfering a result set. With this approach, you are even capable of multi-inheritence, though I don't think that you would want to have it in your use case.At least, I have no better idea here...